# Unity rotating parent so that child's position matches with point

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, quaternions

Let say there is a transform called P, its child called C and a random point on a world called K. I want to rotate P so that C's position became equal or closest to K. How can i do it? I searched Quaternions, LookAt, Inverse etc. but didnt make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have properties assigned for:

```
Transform parentP;      // Parent transform
Transform childC;       // Child transform
Transform randomPointK; // Random point transform
```

You can call the following function `RotateToClosest` to rotate the parent so that the child is closest to the random point. Rotation is independent of any axis and can be applied immediately since we are using Quaternions:

```
void RotateParentToClosest()
{
    // Calculate vectors from parent to child and from parent to random point
    Vector3 toChild = childC.position - parentP.position;
    Vector3 toRandomPoint = randomPointK.position - parentP.position;

    // Calculate the rotation to align toChild with toRandomPoint vectors
    Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(toChild, toRandomPoint);

    // Apply the rotation to the parent
    parentP.rotation = desiredRotation * parentP.rotation;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! It didnt completely solve my problem but it is a correct answer for given question

Answer (score 1):

First get the directions from parent to child and from parent to other object.
Once you have those 2 direction vectors, get the signed angle between them.
This angle is the amount you need to rotate the parent by.

```
var childDirection = (child.position - transform.position);
var otherDirection = (other.position - transform.position);

var angle = Vector3.SignedAngle(childDirection, otherDirection, Vector3.up);

transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, angle, 0));
```

The above assumes you are rotating around the up axis.  You can change the axis by replacing the axis parameter in the SignedAngle function, and changing the rotation vector component.